# Cannot debug a CFC using CFDump and CFFile

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I created a CFC for processing a query, but I cannot use `cfdump` and `cffile` for debugging purpose. The CFC is called via ajax. How can I debug the variable output in the CFC page and show the output?

Comment: Why not? Just because it is ultimately invoked via ajax, does not mean debugging should be done that way. Test it as you would any function - from CF. Call the function from a separate script and dump the results as usual, or for "remote" functions invoke it via URL in a browser [as described below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39273875/104223).

Answer (score 1):

Using Firebug or other network browser plugin, right click on the ajax reply. Then select Open in New Tab. Then, the new tab shows the output. EX: https://xmlsvc.allstartravel.com/locations.cfm?callback=jQuery1101035753620804111186_1472739659659&q=lax&_=1472739659660
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to call the CFC directly from a URL, if your functions are set to allow this, ie `access="remote"`.  You can always change the access level temporarily.

You would call the specific function by using the `method` URL parameter like so:

http://path.to.your.cfc?method=yourfunctionname&argname1=agrvalue1&argname2=argvalue2